# Switch fontawesome icon on click, not working

Tags: javascript, font-awesome-5

I need a fontawesome icon to change to another fontawesome icon when clicked.  I have an "empty" heart icon and it needs to change to a "full heart" once it's clicked.  I've searched for different JS scripts but none seem to work, so I'm clearly doing something wrong, but can't tell what.

**EDITION**
I forgot to mention, and I apologize for it, that one icon should take over the other.  Basically first I'll see the "empty" heart in grey. When hove, the empty heart should go green (just the borders), once it has been clicked, then the heart turns "full" and green.

```js
$('.heart-toggle-empty').click(function() {
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fas fa-heart')
});
$('.heart-toggle-full').blur(function() {
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('far fa-heart')
});
```

```css
.product-icon-heart,
.product-icon-heart-full {
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #D6D4D4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-icon-heart:hover,
.product-icon-heart-full:hover {
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #8ABE57;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- FONT AWESOME -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="col-12 product-icons">
  <div class="col-4 d-inline-block product-icon-heart mr-0">
    <a class="heart-toggle-empty">
      <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 inline-block product-icon-heart-full mr-0">
    <a class="heart-toggle-full">
      <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you seem to be missing jquery library..<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> . $ syntax to retrieve a class is genrally associated with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here you go. I had to rewrite a bit of the code to get what you wanted, but it works now.

```js
$('.heart-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fas far');
});
```

```css
.product-icon-heart {
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.product-icon-heart .heart-toggle {
  color: #D6D4D4;
}
.product-icon-heart .heart-toggle .fas {
  color: #8ABE57;
}
.product-icon-heart .heart-toggle:hover {
  color: #8ABE57;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- FONT AWESOME -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="col-12 product-icons">
  <div class="col-4 d-inline-block product-icon-heart mr-0">
    <a class="heart-toggle" href="#">
      <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 inline-block product-icon-heart mr-0">
    <a class="heart-toggle full" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next code and tellme if works:

```
$('.heart-toggle-empty').click(function() {
  $(this).empty().html('<i class="fas fa-heart text-success"></i>');
});
```

Also, like **meteor** says, add the jQuery library.

Comment: Whats happen with the anchor tag? I just empty his content and replace with new html code. The anchor tag has the class  "heart-toggle-empty".

Comment: Yea, it was just an example for the first case. The anchor tag is not removed. From documentation of jQuery: _empty() "Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM"_.

Comment: It is almost working. The only thing missing is for the "full heart" to stay green when clicked. Right not it stays grey.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Here's a recording of what is happening right now:
https://www.screenmailer.com/v/eaIrOQwpp8tY0Tw

Comment: Since you are using bootstrap. you could add text-success class too. I will edit previous code with this change. You alway can create a custom CSS class and put it in replace of text-success.

Comment: I had no idea text-success existed. Looking forward for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180603/discussion-between-paula-and-d-smania).

Comment: Check here: [Boostrap Colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/)

Answer (score 0):

Your click handlers were toggling the wrong classes, I fixed them in the snippet below, now you can toggle either heart between full and empty:

```js
$('.heart-toggle-empty').click(function() {
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('far fas')
});
$('.heart-toggle-full').click(function() {
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('far fas')
});
```

```css
.product-icon-heart,
.product-icon-heart-full {
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #D6D4D4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-icon-heart:hover,
.product-icon-heart-full:hover {
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #8ABE57;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- FONT AWESOME -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-12 product-icons">
  <div class="col-4 d-inline-block product-icon-heart mr-0">
    <a class="heart-toggle-empty">
      <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 inline-block product-icon-heart-full mr-0">
    <a class="heart-toggle-full">
      <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```